# JQuery - How to: Duplicate <li> and put it to the end of the <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, duplicates, html-lists

I have an ordinary ul li.
I want to attach an li to the list which is based on the first li in the list.

html

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul>
<li>Point Nr 1<p>lol</p></li>
<li>Point Nr 2</li>
<li>Point Nr 3</li>
<li>Point Nr 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

pseudo javascript/jquery

```
$("#gallery ul li").first().duplicate(attachTo:"#gallery ul li")
```

This is what it looks like:

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul>
<li>Point Nr 1<p>lol</p></li>
<li>Point Nr 2</li>
<li>Point Nr 3</li>
<li>Point Nr 4</li>
<li>Point Nr 1<p>lol</p></li>
</ul>
</div
```

How do I do this? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it should be

```
var ul = $('#gallery ul');
ul.find('li:first').clone(true).appendTo(ul);
```

Comment: It's actually considered bad practice to `re-query` an already queried element. Unless it's necessary, you really should use a cache.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
var $gallery = $('#gallery');
$gallery.find('li:first').clone(true).appendTo($gallery.find('ul'));
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/22/

Ref.: [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: this is wrong and this will be very dangerous in IE series because you are duplicating the first li that's OK but you are appending it to div not an ul. so the appended li tags don't nested with an ul. This will not be valid HTML for W3C and should avoid such as this things for sake of IE.

Comment: @Fatih: indeed, I forgot the `.find()`

Comment: I think, your code is not a good practice because, you're using **.find()** 2 times and which is not required. Why you are deeping from parent div, althought deeping from ul. with this you will not to find the ul at the end of code again.

Comment: @Fatih: well, since I'm calling `.find()` on a cached reference, this happens with the speed of light, plus you still have an active reference to the parent `div`.